# Dropdown button: Update text on selection for a single button on the page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a page that has a bunch of dropdown buttons  such as this:

```
    <div class=\"button middle dropdown\"><a href=\"#\">Engineer</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href=\"#\">Name1</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\">Name2</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class=\"button middle dropdown\"><a href=\"#\">Engineer</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href=\"#\">Name1</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#\">Name2</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

On the same page I have this jQuery to update the text on the dropdown button to the one that is selected:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button.middle.dropdown ul li a").click(function() {
            var oldtext = $(".button.middle.dropdown a").html();
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".button.middle.dropdown a").html(text);
            $(this).html(oldtext);
            $(".button.middle.dropdown a ul").hide();
        });     
    });
```

The problem is that this updates the text for ALL of the buttons on the page rather than just the one that was selected.  It obviously does this since the jquery code is updateing everywhere that there is a `.button.middle.dropdown a`.  I would add `id=""` to the `<a>` but these buttons are created dynamically upon loading the page (from a sql query).  How can I get the dropdown button to update the text on only the dropdown button that was pressed?

Comment: Inside of the handler you need to use $(this). I'd assign a class to your hrefs: `a href=\"#\" class="abutton">Engineer</a>` so you can distinguish 2 types of links.

Comment: Since this is all created dynamically, every button's text will be assigned the class of abutton, which will still update the displayed text for all the buttons on the page, not just the one clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`

Instead of

```
$(".button.middle.dropdown a").html();
```

Use

```
$(this).html();
```

**FULL CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button.middle.dropdown ul li a").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $link = $this.closest('.button.dropdown').children('a');
        var oldtext = $link.html();
        var text = $this.html();
        $link.html(text);
        $this.html(oldtext);
        $(".button.middle.dropdown a ul").hide();
    });
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5msJ2/)**

Comment: Doing this only updates the thing I select in the dropdown list, not the text displayed on the dropdown button which is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry! That didn't display the first time I checked! This is awesome, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Thud .. Glad to have helped :)